# Datastax Cassandra Driver Retry Policy Delay?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I am using the Datastax Cassandra driver and have a RetryPolicy setup to retry when a host is unavailable.  However, I have noticed that it retries as fast as it can.  I would like to change it to have an increasing delay between retries rather than hammer the cluster if it is struggling.  This is particularly important for `OVERLOADED` request errors since I do want to retry in these scenarios, but with a substantial delay.

Where is the right place to put a delay and what is the right mechanism?  Should I just throw a `Thread.sleep(...)` in my RetryPolicy?

I don't mind taking up a request on-the-wire slot (towards the maximum number of in-flight requests) but I am not okay with completely blocking other writes if we are not yet at the in-flight request limit.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your own retry policy by adding a delay. The simplest way is to pick the source code of the default retry and modify it yourself to implement an exponential delay for retry or something similar.

For exponential delay, just look at the source code of http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.0/com/datastax/driver/core/policies/ExponentialReconnectionPolicy.html to see how it works

Comment: I already have an ExponentialReconnectionPolicy setup, but it appears that it isn't used in the case of timeout retry decisions.  Maybe it is used for unavailable decisions, though it doesn't appear so.

The way the exponential reconnection policy works is by asking the implementor to provide a timeout and then Cassandra manages the delay.  In the case of RetryDecisions, it doesn't appear that I have an option for giving a delay so I would have to `Thread.sleep()`.  I am concerned that sleeping inside of a retry policy is the wrong thing to do as it may block a request thread.

Comment: Well RetryPolicy != ReconnectionPolicy ... Just create your own ExponentialRetryPolicy

Comment: your concerns about sleeping in a RetryPolicy are valid, the retry is evaluated in a Netty worker, so if you sleep in any of the on* methods it'll block a netty worker thread.

Comment: Hmmm... so I'll need to find another way to delay the next retry.  :/

Comment: @MicahZoltu, I have the same concern as you. Were you able to find another way to delay the next retry?

Comment: @TimOjo This is a mildly old SO question so I went and checked my code to see what I ended up doing, and found this gem: `// TODO: right now it appears that we hammer the cluster as hard as we can.  we should backoff instead`

Comment: @MicahZoltu gotta love those TODO comments ;-)

Comment: @AndyTolbert Can you elaborate on the ramifications of the blocked netty worker?  Do you have any recommendations on how to delay?

Comment: Blocking a netty worker could both prevent writes and reads on a network socket.   I think this makes using a delay via RetryPolicy a non-starter.  Instead the best route is to handle the exceptions in your client code and schedule retries of session.execute at that level.

Comment: Hey I have similar concern, were you guys able to find a good solution?